# Strikethrough comments with Jupyter Notebook Markdown

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Is this possible to Strikethrough my comments with Jupyter Notebook Markdown?

I've tried many options:

```
~~Strike~~
~Strike~
<s>Strike</s>
<strike>Strike<strike>
...
```

nothing is working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are referring to commented-out text inside of your code cells, then markdown formatting will not be applied to the text.  You'd have to put the text in a separate markdown cell instead, then the syntax you noted for strikethrough will work.

Answer (score 5):

Yes I tried this in Jupyter notebook and all of them are working.

Comment: Can you please reassure me that you tried them on *comments* rather than plain text?

Comment: @greybeard see mgleahy's answer. Application of markdown formatting only happens at the whole cell level.

Answer (score 0):

In the notebook toolbar, choose cell >> cell type >> markdown to change the current cell type first.

I verified this grammar  ~strike text~, which works in notebook server 6.4.10

U can try other types of grammar, here is ref: https://mljar.com/blog/jupyter-notebook-bold-italic-strikethrough-underline/